# Was an answer deleted? How can I view the deleted answer?

Tags: support

I got an answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72175/nominal-connectors-in-embedded-sentences-%e5%90%8d%e8%a9%9e-%e5%bd%a2%e5%ae%b9%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e-%ef%bc%8b-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-%e3%81%aa-%e7%ad%89-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e5%88%86%e3%81%91%e3%81%ab) from [@sbkgs4686](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/35632/sbkgs4686), and I was planning on accepting it after I finished reading it and thinking about it, but a few days later I noticed the answer seemed to have been deleted despite having a couple upvotes, and despite the question having a couple stars. I was wondering if someone more knowledgeable or privileged than me could:

> 1) Tell me if the answer has actually been deleted or if I'm just an
>   idiot and don't know how to use the site
>
> 2) Tell me if the answer was likely deleted because it was actually
>   incorrect (so that I can stop trying to remember what the details of
>   the answer were)
>
> 3) Send me the original answer (which I really ought to have saved
>   with the wayback machine or a screenshot...will do from now on)

I wanted to contact the author but it seems like there's no way to do that, so I'm just shouting into the void here.

I don't have a lot of reputation, so I would hate to try and solve this by opening a bounty on the question only to have the same user give the same answer or something.

Comment: I deleted the answer because after thinking some more about the subject, it wasn't nearly as cut-and-dry as I was making it out to be, and I didn't want to confuse anyone with my accidental oversimplification. Sorry for the confusion! Though I do stand by my explanation of ウチとソト; I can repost just that bit if you'd like, even though it doesn't answer your entire question.

Comment: @sbkgs4686 whatever you can post would be helpful. Maybe posting the whole thing and crossing out the parts you don't agree with anymore and/or adding a note about that would also help to avoid confusion or people jumping to conclusions when they read the answer.

Comment: I've undeleted just the ウチとソト part.